# Подключение к контроллеру ДГУ с помощью Ethernet, com-порт java

Tags: java, com-порт, ethernet, modbus

Мне надо написать мониторинг Дизель генераторной установки, протокол буду использовать Modbus, на сколько я понял через Ethernet я смогу подключиться по tcp, а через com-port - rs-232. Можете что нибудь годное накидать по этой теме ? Мне надо в максимально короткие сроки это реализовать(до двух дней). Адреса по которым обращаться за нужными мне параметрами у меня есть, мне надо как то подключиться к com-порту который будет идти от контроллера к ПК и аналогично с Ethernet, что мне для этого знать надо ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На ДГУ, как я понимаю, уже стоит какой-то контроллер. Или есть подключённый. http://fizzed.com/oss/rxtx-for-java - rxtx, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232 - описание протокола, и вот такой API https://github.com/PyramidTechnologies/jPyramid-RS-232 попался на глаза.

На Хабре статья: https://habrahabr.ru/post/71072/

P.S.: А к контроллеру есть какое-нибудь ПО? Драйвера хотя бы?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вот у меня есть таблица адресов http://imgur.com/iDMndr7, по этим адресам мне обращаться к порту и читать в ответ поток байтов ? Если я вас правильно понял то ПО в ответ и должно же отправлять адреса.

Comment: всмысле не адреса, а параметры ДГУ(давления масла, обороты двигателя и т.п), а отвечать по адресам которые я приложил в таблицу

Comment: Судя по картинке, Вы будет обращаться по указанным адресам и получать набор байтов, да. В ответ ПО будет отправлять данные размером указанным в третьей колонке (16 бит, 32 бита, 8 бит для разных адресов). Ваша задача будет их правильно считать и интерпретировать (см. коэффициенты в 4 колонке). Какой адрес за какой параметр отвечает указано в последней колонке.

Comment: Да. Вы опрашиваете адреса и интерпретируете данные. В целом всё. Для управляющих воздействий должна быть другая таблица. Если есть.

Comment: отлично, буду разбираться! и еще хотел спросить какие настройки мне надо будет указать при подключении через com-порт ?

Comment: Как раз хотел добавить: нужно будет указать, на какой скорости будет идти обмен данными. Нужно, чтобы Вы считывали данные не быстрее, чем контроллер способен их предоставлять. А то будет мусор вместо корректных данных. Скорость шины или как-то так будет параметр называться.

Comment: Тоесть мне надо узнать скорость шины контроллера и на порядок медленее считывать данные ?

Comment: И посмотрите описание rs-232 здесь: http://www.softelectro.ru/rs232.html (много информации именно по аппаратной части, загляните сразу в заключение - увидите подводные камни и параметры, на которые нужно обратить внимание - скорость обмена данными, важность отсутствия разрывов в подключении и т.д.)

Comment: Не на порядок медленнее, а не быстрее. Лучше точную скорость подобрать или любую допустимую, на которой вы стабильно будете получать полный набор данных.

Comment: Скорее всего, всё уже "обёрнуто" в rxtx. Сразу исследуйте документацию его лучше. А потом за тонкостями - к документации rs-232 и Ethernet обращайтесь.

Comment: А что скажете по поводу jamod ? Она вроде бы rs-232 и tcp/ip поддерживает, то что мне надо

Comment: Судя по тому, что я увидел на их страничке (http://jamod.sourceforge.net/) - почему бы и нет?

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но все же, как открыть соединение с com-портом и прочитать данные по регистрам я примерно понял, но не могу понять как же java узнает к какому порту мне подключиться, ведь их может одновременно в комп подключено быть несколько ? Есть параметр portname я подозреваю что это оно и есть, но тогда как мне узнать имя подключаемого порта ? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Мы работаем по rs-232 через один из COM-портов, верно? Их ограниченное количество. Список портов, вероятно, доступен в обвязке (API), скорее всего, через объект соединения. Если Вам удалось подключиться, значит API имеет доступ к порту, значит информация о нём (о них) должна быть доступна через объект соединения. http://jamod.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/wimpi/modbus/util/SerialParameters.html -> `public String getPortName()`. А ещё там вроде HowTo есть: http://jamod.sourceforge.net/kb/serial_slave_howto.html